# How to read response from socket when it is connected?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets

in my project I am maintaining an asynchronous Socket connection to send messages to the cell phones. So, my problem is as this connection is asynchronous so when for long time no data arrives the remote server socket closes the connection automatically. So, my requirement is to make the connection alive always for 24 hours even if no data transmitting. And my client also wants to see receiving and sending status all the time. So that they can understand that something is happening. But I am quite new in this so I need help to achieve this need. Any help will be appreciated.

My question is:

1. Is it possible that when a socket is connected to the server socket it receives some bytes? even if there is no data to transmit at all?
2. If after connecting the client socket receive some data then how can I achieve this?

Below is my code for BeginReceive() and Callback method:

```
  #region Receive & ReceiveCallBack
    public void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        if (m_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }

        else
        {
            Connect();
        }
    }

    public void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (m_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            string receiveData = "";
            string sendData = "";

            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                state.sb.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);

                receiveData = state.sb.ToString();
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => IsBulk.Items.Add(receiveData)));

                sendData = getReply(receiveData);
                write_log(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + receiveData, "bytesRead", "bytesRead");

                try
                {
                    Object objData = sendData;
                    byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());
                    if (m_clientSocket != null)
                    {
                        m_clientSocket.Send(byData);
                    }

                    write_log(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + sendData, "sendData", "sendData");
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                    logstr = se.Message;
                    write_log(logstr, "WaitForData", "waitfordata");
                }

            }
            else
            {

                receiveData = state.sb.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(receiveData))
                {
                    write_log(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + receiveData, "receiveData2", "receiveData2");
                }


                receiveDone.Set();
            }
            state.sb.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            Connect();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void Connect()
    {

        m_clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("10.151.41.134");

        int iPortNo = System.Convert.ToInt16("6561");

        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, iPortNo);

        m_clientSocket.Connect(ipEnd);

        if (m_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            this.stStatus.Text = "Server Connected";

            timer3.Enabled = true;
            timer4.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.stStatus.Text = "Server Failed to Connect";
            m_clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        }

    }
```

UPDATE: This is what I have to show in the windows program:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a library to do this? I recommend SignalR.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I don't know much about library of socket.

Comment: My point is that I would recommend against using sockets altogether but abstract away the problem. SignalR is a library for creating asynchronous push based two way communication over a network. Then you just deal with `messages` rather than sockets and bytes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am sure that you are suggesting a much better approach than this. But it would be easier for me to understand if you provide some sample code for demonstration. Thank you.

Comment: [SignalR documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki)

Comment: You may also consider [XSockets](http://xsockets.net/) which has less dependency on Windows 8

Comment: Thanks a lot I will check these documents.